The most common one (L)
What 5-letter word is depicted below?

             SUBTRACT
         ADD


             SUBTRACT
         ADD 
              
           

         SUBTRACT     SUBTRACT
         
SUBTRACT ADDNOTHINGADDNOTHING SUBTRACT 
         ADDNOTHINGADDNOTHING
         ADDNOTHINGADDNOTHING
SUBTRACT ADDNOTHINGADDNOTHING SUBTRACT
        
         SUBTRACT     SUBTRACT


The answer is

 water

because

 "ADD", "SUBTRACT", and "NOTHING" can be taken to represent protons (which have a positive charge), electrons (which have a negative charge), and neutrons (which have 0 charge).

 At the top, we have two combinations of a single proton and a single electron. That's two hydrogen atoms.

 At the bottom, we have a nucleus consisting of eight neutrons and eight protons, and eight electrons on the outside. That's an oxygen atom.

 Two hydrogen atoms, and one oxygen atoms... that's water!


Correct, well done! The title just refered to the most common form (on earth) rot13(Yvdhvq)

Congratulations on 150k reputation!
